# Connected subset of Real number

Tags: real-analysis

I know Interior of connected subset of R is connected but is the interior of connected subset of R^2 is connected?

Comment: Consider two closed circles that touch tangentially at a single point

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to MSE!  We expect that the questions posed here come with an explanation of what you have tried and what specific things you are stuck on.  Try editing your question to fit [these standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and I am sure you will get an answer that helps you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Consider the set of two closed balls connected by a segment given by
$$C=\bar{B}_1((0,0))\cup \bar{B}_1((3,0))\cup[1,2]\times \{0\}$$

this set is connected whereas its interior is given by
$$C=B_1((0,0))\cup B_1((3,0))$$
Which is disconnected.

Tried to add pictures in jpeg but somehow server did not let me.